# How to check the class id is registered or not?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, com, registry

Hi i am checking the GUID of **SqlClass which is in my Test.dll** But it does not give success it failed with value... Whatis wrong in this code.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std; 

int main() {
  HKEY hk;

  long n = RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT,TEXT("\\CLSID\\SqlClass"),
                  0,KEY_QUERY_VALUE, &hk );"
  if ( n == ERROR_SUCCESS ) {
    cout << "OK" << endl;
  }
  else {
    cout << "Failed with value " << n << endl;
  }
}
```

I tried like this also RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT,TEXT("\CLSID\46A951AC-C2D9-48e0-97BE-91F3C9E7B065"),
                      0,KEY_QUERY_VALUE, &hk )

**THIS CODE WORKS FINE**

```
    #include < windows.h >
    # include < iostream >
    using namespace std; 

   int main() {
               HKEY hk;

               long n = RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT,
           TEXT("\\CLSID\\{46A951AC-C2D9-48e0-97BE-91F3C9E7B065}"),
              0,KEY_QUERY_VALUE, &hk );"
           if ( n == ERROR_SUCCESS ) {
               cout << "OK" << endl;
             }
            else {
                 cout << "Failed with value " << n << endl;
                }
         }
```

Comment: Is the value really present in the registry at that path?

Comment: In the second code snippet the GUID must be enclosed in "{" and "}". Look how other GUIDs are stored in the registry.

Comment: Comments Are Helpful Thanks Sharptooth

Answer (score 2):

I've never seen anything other than a GUID under CLSID, so the key probably doesn't exist.  Look in that node under regedit to see what I mean.

What was the failure code, n?  You can look this up in two ways

1. Put the number into the "Error Lookup" tool in Visual Studio's Tools menu.
2. Call [FormatMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms679351(VS.85).aspx) on n, which gives you the text associated with that error.

Comment: +1. It's typical to have symbolic keys at HKCR level, not in HKCR\CLSID

Comment: Error code with value "2" which you probably have means "file not found" (favorite error on tdwtf :))

Comment: Error Code 2 is Appearing But i seach under regedit as Test
it shown under
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{46A951AC-C2D9-48E0-97BE-91F3C9E7B065}

Comment: It's unclear what you want. Do you need to find the GUID by string "Test.SqlClass"?

Comment: In regedit find your registered GUID, right click and select "export". The path on the bottom is what you want to check for. GUIDs are enclosed with {}, so try 
RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT, TEXT("CLSID\\{46A951AC-C2D9-48e0-97BE-91F3C9E7B065}"), 0, KEY_QUERY_VALUE, &hk);